# Python Pandas: Dataframe is not updating using string methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to update the strings in a `.csv` file that I am reading using Pandas. The `.csv` contains the column name 'about' which contains the rows of data I want to manipulate.

I've already used str. to update but it is not reflecting in the exported `.csv` file. Some of my code can be seen below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.About.str.lower() #About is the column I am trying to update
df.About.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z ]', '')
df.to_csv('newdata.csv')
```

Comment: Try `df['About'].str.lower()` instead

Comment: Try assigning the value to column `df.About = df.About.str.lower()`

Comment: @caricature, if the answer posted below helped solve your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign output to column, also is possible chain both operation together, because working with same column `About` and because values are converted to lowercase, is possible change `regex` to replace not uppercase:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.About = df.About.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z ]', '')
df.to_csv('newdata.csv', index=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'About':['AaSD14%', 'SDD Aa']})

df.About = df.About.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z ]', '')
print (df)
    About
0    aasd
1  sdd aa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['About']
data = ["ALPHA","OMEGA","ALpHOmGA"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.About = df.About.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-zA-Z ]', '')
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

[image: out]

Answer (score 1):

**Example Dataframe**:

```
>>> df
        About
0      JOHN23
1     PINKO22
2   MERRY jen
3  Soojan San
4      Remo55
```

**Solution:**,another way Using a compiled regex with flags

```
>>> df.About.str.lower().str.replace(regex_pat,  '')
0          john
1         pinko
2     merry jen
3    soojan san
4          remo
Name: About, dtype: object
```

**Explanation:**

> Match a single character not present in the list below `[^a-z]+`
>
> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) a-z a single character in
>   the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
>
> `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: I think OP need something else.

Comment: So `added` only `$ asserts position at the end of a line` for difference with my answer :( It is really bad :(

Comment: OK, so use only second solution, it is regex also bad

Comment: Sure, you miss whitespace and end of file is not necessary.